# for loop is not stopping why? even I specifically say to stop on 10 in condition

Tags: javascript

```
for(var i = 0; i <= 10; i+1){
console.log(i); // the loop goes on and on
}
```

why this for loop don't stop ? I did specifically typed in condition that it need to stop on 10.

Comment: ...but `i` does never reach 10 right?

Comment: Please read a tutorial, or go for a walk for ten minutes, depending on the situation.

Comment: you are right man

Answer (score 3):

The `i+1` is your issue. It should be `i = i + 1`, `i++` or `i+=1`

These are just different ways of adding 1 to the current value of `i`

```js
for(var i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
  console.log(i); 
}
```

Comment: sorry for asking this simple question.

Answer (score 0):

You never change `i`.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i + 1) {
                         ^^^^^
```

You need to increment `i`

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {        // or
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i = i + 1) {
```

Answer (score 0):

It's missing the `=`: i is not being mutated:

```
for(var i = 0; i <= 10; i += 1){
  console.log(i); // the loop goes on and on
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to `i++` and it will work.  Right now you are just checking against `0+1` every loop iteration, and that will never be > 10.